# how to use BPF filter to filter packet payload?

Tags: networking, bpf

I need to do a homework about analysis some packets.
I found that BPF filtering is a good thing for my homework, I want to filter all packet that have a payload that start with a specific string like "Test it". The packets are combination of TCP,UDP,ICMP and some may not even have a payload.
How can I set the filter?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer,
http://www.foo.be/cours/dess-20112012/bpf/bpf.pdf

in this pdf, there is a place talking about BPF syntax to filter payload. The following is from the pdf, in this way, we can use the BPF to skip the header
An example, you want to match "GE" string in a TCP payload :
echo -n "GE" | hexdump -C
00000000 47 45 |GE|
sudo tcpdump -s0 -n -i ath0 "tcp[20:2] = 0x4745"

Comment: I do think the original question is about "floating" text matching.  Your example is assuming that a text string is starting at a fixed offset from the beginning.  BPF does not do "floating text matching".

Comment: BPF has undergone some rework during the last years, and the new version now enables some backward jumps. It still has restrictions for the loops, so I do not know if you could test the presence of the string at _each_ offset of the payload… Might be interesting to check.

Answer (score 0):

A classic example of how you can filter out `HTTP GET` requests with tcpdump and BPF filters

```
tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2):4]
```

There is a good explanation about above filter in details
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/121011/wireshark-tcp-filter-tcptcp121-0xf0-24
https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters